# CGGetcurrentContext en UIview

Tags: swift

No entiendo de dónde sale el método dicho en el título ni las demás clases con el prefijo 'CG', de core graphics. Busqué el framework 'Core Graphics' pero no aparece en UIKIT ni en en Cocoa touch.

Una cosa más, que sería un contexto? Lo leí en la api pero no lo entendí.

Answer (score 1):

`CGGetCurrentContext` es el indicativo para el contexto en CoreGraphics.

```
let miContexto = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
CGContextSaveGState(miContexto);
```

El contexto puede definirse como una referencia que necesita el Sistema Operativo para saber donde se esta guardando la información, por ejemplo en que UIImageView tienes almacenada una imagen.

Esta definición me parece acertada para CG:

> El contexto dice a cada llamada CG dónde encontrar todas estas "cosas"
>   de su llamada “Drawing" actual. Da un contexto diferente para la misma
>   llamada de dibujo, y esa llamada podría dibujar un mapa de bits
>   diferente en una vista completamente diferente, con un color
>   diferente, diferente escala, etc.

definición tomada de:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772392/ios-current-graphics-context-what-is-that/4772545#4772545 (inglés)